# Meaning of the phrases: Defuse confrontation / What's unfolding

Tags: phrase-meaning

I'm a English leaner and I ran into an article.
There were 2 phrases I couldn't get the meaning.

> ... attempting to **defuse the early morning confrontation** in the doorway ...
>
> ... tries to explain **what's unfolding** to the dispatcher ...

["Stunning SFPD bodycam video shows DePape's violent assault of Paul Pelosi" - CBS News]

Below is the link.

https://www.cbsnews.com/sanfrancisco/news/stunning-sfpd-bodycam-video-shows-david-depape-attack-paul-pelosi/

Anyone who would rephrase them using easier words is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: You _defuse_ a bomb to stop it exploding. This is a metaphorical use.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you, I think I get the meaning!

Comment: You can find a secondary meaning of _unfold_ in a dictionary.

Comment: @KateBunting -  it annoys me when I see situations being 'diffused' in news reports.

Comment: Hi Lucy, I also lean to English these days :) Jokes aside, please focus on one question when you post a question here. You can simply ask two different questions. This way, you get more focused answers. Welcome to ELL!

Comment: Welcome to ELL. I hope you like the place and decide to visit often. You might want to read the [Contributor's guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4783/91457). It has a lot of helpful information on how best to ask and answer, questions here on ELL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To defuse means to deactivate an explosive device to prevent it from exploding.

In your example, to defuse is being used metaphorically. It means "to stop the early morning confrontation".